# Displaying list of addresses in Drupal module

Tags: php, drupal, module

I'm trying to build a three step custom module for Drupal 7.

- First page is a postcode search
- Second page is a list of property addresses relating to the postcode
- Third page is the full bin calendar details for that property.

The actual information is not that important, the important part that I'm struggling with is displaying the list of addresses on page2 after the user has submitted the postcode. This list will be a list of links that will link to page3.

Comment: You can ask questions related to Drupal on Drupal Stack Exchange `http://drupal.stackexchange.com/`

Comment: post your code.. what did u try?

Comment: What's your question? Currently this looks like a specification you want to be fulfilled/tutored through - that's not what Stack Overflow (or Drupal Answers) is for. If you're posting to either site, make sure you include the code that isn't working, and describe the expected/actual results in detail